# Has the hard drive been accessed or computer hacked?

Tags: windows, audit, physical

How do I find out if someone who had access to my laptop, accessed the
   hard drive manually (by taking it out of the laptop and copying or
   viewing the data)?

I know there is the Windows audit policy for actual log-ins, is that reliable to know if someone accessed your hard drive without
   removing it?

Comment: On a side note, you can mitigate a high percentage of threats by simply encrypting the drive with full disk encryption. Bitlocker, veracrypt, etc... make it very difficult for someone to get data even if they make an image.

Comment: technically if you don't have protected  BIOS, person who has access to your laptop could run OS from USB stick and make backup your entire disc without taking it out. And that will be hard to detect, but it can be prevented by encrypting your drive

Comment: Just mentioning that if you are full disk encrypted and the computer turned off .. it doesnt matter.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to detect tampering, you'd want to apply a [tamper evident sticker](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=tamper+evident+sticker&tbm=shop&oq=tamper+evident+sticker&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.3..0.4163.6353.0.7008.2.2.0.0.0.0.351.649.2-1j1.2.0....0...1..34.mobile-heirloom-serp..0.2.647.sm75y8ZJKj4) on the computer case or drive's port. It's not fool proof, but it'll make tampering without getting detected a lot more tricky.

It's easiest to apply the sticker on the case. Although you may want to also apply the sticker on the cable ports, on the motherboard side and the drive side, if you can find a sticker that's small enough for it and sticks to the surface of the connectors.

Best way to prevent unauthorized copying though, is to encrypt the drive. They'll still be able to copy the data, but without the decryption key, the copied data is useless.

Answer (score 1):

If someone had physical access to the drive itself there would be no way to tell if a bit by bit copy was made. This is how I would start any forensic investigation. Making a simple image of a drive can be done via linux tools such as:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=somefile.image
```

Creating such a copy would mean I have total access to the drive whenever I want in exactly the state you gave it to me. I could hand you the drive right back and use the image from that point forward. I don't think there is any way to tell whether this has been done as it is a bit by bit read only copy.

As for actual windows policies, there are features for logging and audit but they are not very expansive by default. It depends on what audit policies you have enabled and how they are configured. But again, if I have physical access, why take the risk. I would just make an image of the drive and do whatever I want with the image later.

I'm afraid I don't know of a "reliable" way to see if something was touched. You can prove something was touched. You can't prove it was not.

***However:***

I'm going to include this for completeness sake, but I highly doubt you will be in the position to take advantage of it. But on one occasion someone had a batch script running on windows that simply uploaded some data to his email  at certain times. It was a very interesting prospect.

Modern hard drives have, what's called, S.M.A.R.T. monitoring. And with a little bit of help from [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) or similar tools (I haven't used smartmontools in a few years so I don't know how it has developed, use your own judgment there) we were able to get information about the drive that did indeed prove it had been tampered with.

Amongst the data we looked at in the output were (id,name,desc):

```
4   Start_Stop_Count    Spindle start/stop cycles
9   Power_On_Hours      Elapsed hours in power-on state
12  Power_Cycle_Count   # of full HDD power on/off cycles
```

Since they had been logging this information, and the drive was large enough for an image to take a while. We were able to look at the cycle count, spindle cycles and the on hours changes to say within reasonable doubt that if given the logging is true and accurate, the drive was accessed out of box. Possibly to make an image.

Now, this required you had already made note of the SMART data beforehand. Its also still highly speculative and relies on accurate recording of information. But it does exist. It can be used. Maybe in your case, for future reference.

Comment: Your answers were very useful. I appreciate it. I read on another website that you can find the last access date for a hard drive, do you know how to do that? It wouldn't be useful this time because I already accessed it after it happened, but could be useful in the future if you know how. I'm surprised that hard drives don't keep records of everytime the hard drive is accessed. Another thing, are there records for everytime (or even just the last time) a computer accesses the internet? how do you find these records?

Comment: The FAT,NTFS, and other file systems have modified,accessed, and created date/time stamps.  In some cases these can be turned off.  The problem is if I used sector level access, there would be no records created.  If someone removes your hard drive, they can attach a write blocker before cloning, and the file system won't have change at all.

Comment: @Mel where do you propose that the disk stores the information of when it was accessed?  After a few years, that information could be greater than the capacity of the disk itself.  Also, a disk has no reason to have a built-in clock (which would require a battery), so it has no way to know *when* anything happens either.

Comment: I found this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646.aspx but it doesn't tell me about any write or read on the hard drive before the time I opened it, and it seems to write a lot on the hard drive, constantly. are there records for the last time a laptop accessed the internet (or everytime it did)? how do you find these records? @cybernard how do you find the last access date stamp if a write blocker wasn't attached?

Comment: @Simon B http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/284828-45-detecting-flash-drive-access if you read this, somehow they got to know the last time the USB was plugged into any computer, how did they do that?

Comment: @Mel That's none by looking at the last accessed time on the files on the disk.  But that still relies on the PC updating that timestamp.  But if you just do a binary copy of the whole disk, then the timestamps won't be updated.  Alternatively, a write blocker prevents the PC from writing anything to the disk - it can only read data.

Answer (score 0):

> how do you find the last access date stamp if a write blocker wasn't
>   attached?

Goto File Explorer or Windows Explorer, and right click see picture.
Click **More**

[image: File explorer right click]
Click more

[image]
Check the box as shown here and then **Ok**

Results are now displayed

Must be run as administrator, if XP has this utility.

```
fsutil usn readjournal c:
```

Comment: Thanks I'll have to go through the files and make sure there's nothing suspicious. Are there records for the last time a laptop accessed the internet or does Windows save IP addresses it connects to?

Comment: As a general rule, no.  However, all browsers have some kind of cache and/or history.  Assuming they were not cleared, that is the only record of connection kept.  If they used a non-web browser no records would be kept, and most browser have a privacy mode they could have utilized.  You would have to turn logging on manually, and it would quickly consume all available hard drive space.  I am sure you noticed diskmon racks up 10,000-50,000 entries in a few minutes.